# Like and Dislike System for Posts

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to include a like/dislike system similar to Facebook and so far, I have set the like/dislike columns as a 'text' type.  This is so that I can add the id for the user(s) who liked/disliked a post.  Would that be the best way of doing it?  Also, in addition to the question above, how would I stop a user pressing the like and dislike button again? Since, once a user has liked a post, it should display an unlike/undislike option?  A concept/idea would be great of how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

While it's hard to make armchair decisions, here are my ideas:

First, you could have a 'likes' integer column for each post. When a user clicks up and down, have that number increment or decrement. This offers no protection against users clicking multiple times, but it's easy and fast.

Another way would be to have a 'Like' table, with columns post_id, user_id, and score. score can have two values: '1' or '-1'. All 3 columns are integers. When the user clicks 'like', you do an INSERT/UPDATE command on the row with user_id & post_id matching.

Then, to see the final score for a post, you do a SELECT SUM(score) FROM that_table WHERE post_id = ?.

With this second method, if you wanted to see the name of the most recent clicker, you could add a timestamp column and search for the most recent entry.

Comment: I'm tempted to choose the Table option having post_id (Posts Table) and user_id (Users Table) as the foreign keys and then score and timestamp as you suggested.  I think for the like/unlike options, I will have to query all the posts that I have applied 1 to and provide an unlike option and do the same for dislike.  Would that be the best way of doing it? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, the foreign keys are what you'd want. Also, you'd probably want to make {post_id + user_id} to be a compound primary key. As for your last question reguarding unlike/dislike, you have to decide what functionality you want. One option is the "unlike" as you said. Another is to just disallow un-liking. A third is that when the user clicks unlike but they've already liked it, it just removes their 'like' without actually making it a 'dislike' (unless they then click it again). That way you don't have to calculate what buttons to show until after they click them :)

Comment: Sounds like some good options, thanks :)  Helpful posts and if only I could up vote you but I need 15 points so someone please +1 this guy.

Comment: Thanks! you can select it as the "correct" answer if you care to. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table with the following structure:

Table: Likes

- PostId bigint
- UserId bigint
- Like bit(true, false)

Then set PostId and UserId together as the primary key.  This will prevent the database from inserting multiple likes/unlikes for the same post.

In your code, check to see if the user/post combination exists and then toggle the bit value if it does or set the bit value to true if it does not.

Comment: I have decided to go with the Table option, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: which method is best to send the like request to db server, `GET` or `POST` method.

Please suggest me for both android an website api call.
-Thanks