# best practice for optimization number of database requests

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on like/dislike system (php+ajax+mysql) .
My system is made like recommended here: [Like and Dislike System for Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169470/like-and-dislike-system-for-posts). So i have many requests to database, for example :

1. when user put like (insert in db)
2. take all likes for this post (select from db)
3. Also when user try to put like,there is checks flag in database.
4. if user tries to put like for this post twice, again check flag via db.

and this is only for one post,but i also have comments,that user can likes.
Is there is a good practice to make this operations via database or it's better to use cache/sessions or something like that.

Comment: Store each vote as a +1 or a -1 in a separate row; you can then do `SUM(votes)` to get the total score easily. Yes, this should be in a database to start with, you can always optimise from there.

Comment: You mean to store all likes for one post in 1 table ? If that,how to check if man already put like ? If so i think the best way will be to make 2 table where will be id_user and vote(bool) ,so when user put like,it made insert/update into 2-nd table and make +1 vote to main table where post_id and sum_likes ?

Comment: Oh i'm understand..i need only 1 table with user_id,post_id and votes,so for each vote will creates new row in db ,and then select sum for this post where will be many user_ids,big thaaaanks,so easy and so awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like it to persist between sessions then you'd have to save it to a database of some sort.

You could have it more efficient by perhaps having a master-slave databases that the slave only do reads and master only writes.

There are more ways to do it, depends on the specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, i thinks about this way, but i really don't know if there is a trouble to talk so much with db or it is a simple practice ?